# Godot read nested dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, godot

I am trying access items in a nest dictionary. Hard coding it is fine dict[string_1][string_1a], but when user is selecting items in the UI and they drill down, I am not sure how to "follow" them. I have a little LineEdit that shows the path such as string_1/string_1 (similar to how computers show folders). However, if I want to create a new item such as [string_1][string_1b], I am not sure how to do that. I am able to print the string with the path [string_1][string_1b], but I don't know how to actually add that back into the dictionary as I can't do str2var (that I am aware of), and I can't simply pass string_1b as it has to be inside string_1.

```
func update_path(object, full_path):
    var new_path = ""
    
    full_path.insert(0, object.get_text(0))
    new_path = object.get_parent()
    
    if new_path != null:
        update_path(new_path, full_path)
    
    else:
        pathEdit.text =  ""
        
        # for some stupid reason I can't remove 0, it throws an error
        for item in full_path:
            if item != "":
                pathEdit.text += item + "/"
```

```
    print("saving subcategory")
    print(pathEdit.text)
    
    var save_path= pathEdit.text.split("/")
    print(save_path)
    
    var dumb_string = "Globals.notebook_data"
    
    for path in save_path:
        if path != "":
            print(path)
            #print(Globals.notebook_data[path])
            #print(Globals.notebook_data[save_path])
            #print("Globals.notebook_data"+ )
            dumb_string += "[" + path + "]"
    
    print(dumb_string)
    print(str2var(dumb_string))
```

The string is the correct path, I just simply don't know how to "access" it. I was thinking of looping through the array, but I am not sure how to tack it on, and if I simply access just that level it doesn't keep the dictionary whole.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, needed to save it recursively.

https://godotengine.org/qa/81247/update-a-dictionary-by-iterating-on-its-keys

```
func set_path(path, value):
    var keypath: PoolStringArray = ["key1","key1_1","key1_1_1","foo"] 
    _set_path(dictionary,keypath,value)

func _set_path(dict,keypath, value):
    var current = keypath[0]
    if dict.has(current):
        if typeof(dict[current]) == TYPE_DICTIONARY:
            keypath.remove(0)
            _set_path(dict[current],keypath, value) # recursion happens here
            return
        else:
            print_debug("found")
            dict[current] = value
            return
    print_debug("not found")
```